# Allocating and initializing a 2D array dynamically using a double pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, segmentation-fault, double-pointer

I'm trying to create a 2D array (5 rows and 2 cols) dynamically. At the time of allocating the memory there's no sort of problem. However, while assigning actual values to the array I got a Segmentation Fault error.
While debugging I got to realize that the error pops up when `i` in the for loop has value 4

How can it be possible to get a segmentation fault error even after allocating with no problem the memory that will be used by the array?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int **ptr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
     for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
         ptr[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
     }
     
     for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
         for(int j = 0; j<2; j++){
             ptr[i][j] = i;
         }
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `sizeof(int) != sizeof(int *)` (assuming a contemporary 64-bit arch) and you need the latter one for the first allocation.

Comment: The argument to `typeof` in the `malloc()` argument should always have 1 less `*` than the pointer you're assigning to. A better approach is to use `sizeof(*ptr)`, then it will work for any pointer type.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Sidenote: keep in mind whether you actually need to use dynamic memory allocation or not.

Comment: Side note: that is *not* a 2D array.  It's unclear why you need dynamic allocation at all, but if you do, then you should consider the advantages of a *bona fide* 2D array over your current array of pointers to 1D arrays.  For example, reserving all the needed memory at once: `int (*ptr)[2] = malloc(5 * sizeof *ptr);`, using less memory overall, and being contiguously allocated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can it be possible to get a segmentation fault error even after allocating with no problem the memory that will be used by the array?

Code did not allocate correctly.  `sizeof(int)*5` is the wrong size in OP's code.

- Avoid allocation errors.  Size to the referenced object, not the type.  It is easier to code right the first time, review and maintain.  In OP's case `sizeof ptr[0]` is the correct size, the size of a pointer.  `sizeof(int)` is incorrect as it is the size of a `int`, yet  the size of a pointer is needed here.
- Casting not needed.
- Better code checks for allocation failures.

```
    // int **ptr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
    int **ptr = malloc(sizeof ptr[0] * 5);
    if (ptr == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory();
```

Comment: I prefere `sizeof *ptr` as it shows that `ptr` is a pointer

Comment: @gulpr I used to do likewise, yet found that `ptr[0]` more clear than `*ptr` as `ptr` becomes more complex like `abc->def[i] = malloc(sizeof abc->def[i][0])` rather than `sizeof *(abc->def[i])` as `[]` binds tighter and associate L-R than `*` and with R-L.

Answer (score 0):

> Allocating and initializing a 2D array

An array of pointers is not a 2D array.

To allocate 2D array I would use pointer to array:

```
void initArray(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*array)[cols])
{
    if(array && rows && cols)
        for(size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
            for(size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                array[row][col] = rand() % 100;
}

void printArray(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*array)[cols])
{
    if(array && rows && cols)
        for(size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            for(size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                printf("%03d ", array[row][col]);
            printf("\n");
        }
}

int main(void)
{
    int (*ptr)[COLS] = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(*ptr));
    if(ptr)
    {
        printf("Allocation OK\n");
        srand(time(NULL));
        initArray(ROWS, COLS, ptr);
        printArray(ROWS, COLS, ptr);
    }
    else
        printf("Allocation FAILED\n");

    free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: check if `!ptr`, print error, then return with an error code. If that isn't triggered, the code in your `if (ptr)` branch can proceed and need not be embedded in a conditional.

Comment: Alternatively the functions can have the parameter as `int array[rows][cols]` which is 100% equivalent but gives more self-documenting code. As in "this array is based on the parameters rows and cols".